# Display block of <a> element

Tags: html, css, flexbox, block, display

I have problem with  element. I want to make it `display: block` element. The problem is that it is not inherit `width` and `height` from `<li>` element.

http://jsfiddle.net/3vL13q1n/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please check this: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
 min-height: 100%;
}

body{
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #D8DBE2;
 color: #D8DBE2;
}

body, .navigation * {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

.navigation{
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 70px;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 background-color: #181E1D;
}

.naviagation__list{
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 justify-content: center;
 float: right;
 width: 55%;
 min-height: 70px;
}

.navigation__item{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 border: 1px solid white;
 width: 25%;
 min-height: 70px;
 list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.navigation__link{
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">

    <ul class="naviagation__list">

        <li class="navigation__item">
            <a href="#" class="navigation__link"> Main page </a>
        </li>

        <li class="navigation__item">
            <a href="#" class="navigation__link"> About us </a>
        </li>

        <li class="navigation__item">
            <a href="#" class="navigation__link"> Products </a>
        </li>

        <li class="navigation__item">
            <a href="#" class="navigation__link"> Contact </a>
        </li>

    </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks! It helps me :)

Comment: @zgrybus: If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use: `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` for `<a>`

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
 min-height: 100%;
}

body{
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #D8DBE2;
 color: #D8DBE2;
}

body, .navigation * {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

.navigation{
 width: 100%;
 min-height: 70px;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 background-color: #181E1D;
}

.naviagation__list{
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 justify-content: center;
 float: right;
 width: 55%;
 min-height: 70px;
}

.navigation__item{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 border: 1px solid white;
 width: 25%;
 min-height: 70px;
 list-style-type: none;
}

.navigation__link{
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: inherit;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 22px
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">

    <ul class="naviagation__list">

        <li class="navigation__item">
            <a href="#" class="navigation__link"> Main page </a>
        </li>

        <li class="navigation__item">
            <a href="#" class="navigation__link"> About us </a>
        </li>

        <li class="navigation__item">
            <a href="#" class="navigation__link"> Products </a>
        </li>

        <li class="navigation__item">
            <a href="#" class="navigation__link"> Contact </a>
        </li>

    </ul>

</nav>
```